# Process S3 data with fair queueing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I have to process data saved to an S3 bucket with key structure `client_id/uid`. Updates to S3 must be processed FIFO. One way to achieve this is to queue updates to SQS, message payload is the S3 key, and then process that.

However, this is not fair if certain clients are pushing way more updates than others.

Suppose I want to make processing fair across client_id. Ideally I would like to receive a batch of queue messages that contain the oldest message for each client_id. The batch must contain one message per client. I'll then start a number of workers to process the batch, once they've all completed proceed to the next iteration.

Is it possible to do this without creating a SQS queue for each client?

Should I consider using a different AWS service instead?

Comment: Take a look [Using the Amazon SQS Message Group ID - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html). It is a way of processing only one message at a time for a given `MessageGroupID`. If this ID is set to your customer identifier, and assuming you have parallel workers, then it would limit each client to only one concurrent worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) pointed me in the right direction with his comment.

Consider a queue with 15 messages each for client. The messages were added like this

```
for message = 1 to 15 {
  for client_id = 1 to 3 {
    sendMessage(messageGroupID=client_id)
  }
}
```

Receiving messages in a loop will fetch the following on each call

```
10 messages for client_id = 1
10 messages for client_id = 2
10 messages for client_id = 3
5 messages for client_id = 1 and 5 messages for client_id = 2
5 messages for client_id = 3
```

The same holds when receiving messages with parallel consumers.

Not exactly how I imagined it would work but it does solve my problem.

Comment: "While messages with a particular MessageGroupId are invisible, no more messages belonging to the same MessageGroupId are returned until the visibility timeout expires. You can still receive messages with another MessageGroupId as long as it is also visible"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html